# How to set value of derived type named constant with allocatable component?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

This compiles correctly:

```
type t1
    integer :: a, b(2), c
end type t1
type(t1), parameter :: t1a = t1(1, [2, 3], 4)
```

I want to write something like this, except that it doesn't compile:

```
type t2
    integer :: a
    integer, allocatable :: b(:)
    integer :: c
end type t2
type(t2), parameter :: t2a = t2(1, [2, 3], 4) ! compile error
type(t2), parameter :: t2b = t2(1, [2, 3, 4], 5) ! compile error
```

The gfortran error message

```
Error: Invalid initialization expression for ALLOCATABLE component 'b' in structure constructor
```

doesn't give me any clue as to the correct syntax.

I don't get any complaint about trying to *declare* a parameter variable with an allocatable type, so I assume there must be *some* way to initialize it!

Answer (score 4):

I think you assume wrong.  The 2008 standard explicitly forbids initialisation of an allocatable entity (R503/C506) and I suspect that it also forbids initialisation of an allocatable entity which is a component of a derived type though I can't find chapter and verse to support my suspicion.

Comment: You may be right. `integer, allocatable :: ab(:) = [2, 3]` gives a fairly explicit error message: `Error: Allocatable 'ab' cannot have an initializer`.

Comment: The standard does not forbid initialization of an allocatable component, but your options for that component are limited to a reference to the intrinsic function NULL(), which corresponds to specifying "not allocated".  See F2008 4.5.10p6 and 7.1.12p1 item 3b for more elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

The expression used to set the value of a named constant, or the initial value of a variable, is a *constant expression*. To be a constant expression an expression which uses a structure constructor is subject to a restriction (Fortran 2018 10.1.12 p1 3a)<sup>1</sup> which means that

> each component-spec corresponding to an allocatable component is a reference to the intrinsic function NULL

This means that you cannot have a named constant with allocatable component which is allocated, and that initially a variable's allocatable component is not allocated.

---

<sup>1</sup> In Fortran 2003, as the question is additionally tagged, the terminology is sightly different, using *initialization expression*, but the equivalent restriction applies.