# Direct Initialization of ALLOCATABLE Variable

Tags: parameters, fortran, derived-types, fortran2008

Can I Directly Initialize a Derived type that has allocatable variable in it.

In the following Program, I want to initialize the derived type variable "Zero" to contain 0. Is it possible?

```
PROGRAM testProgram

TYPE IntegerType
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: Num
END TYPE IntegerType

TYPE(IntegerType), PARAMETER :: Zero = IntegerType(ALLOCATE(0))


print*, Zero

END PROGRAM testProgram
```

Comment: You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32876256/3157076) have an allocated component in the initialization expression.

Comment: (Note also that with the allocatable component, you'd also need to provide a defined output procedure to be able to handle that `print` statement. That's not relevant to the initialization problem, though.)

Comment: I solved the problem by adding type procedure which equates parameter(0) to variable called, `PROCEDURE, PASS(self), PUBLIC :: Zero ` . So, here, Zero procedure when called `CALL  IT%Zero()` using derived type variable, it will equate the derived type IT with Integer 0.

Comment: @AkhilAkkapelli that is quite a neat workaround. Would you consider adding it as an answer to the duplicate question linked by Francescalus?

Comment: I have an improved answer, I will test it and add it soon @veryreverie